# Why Spring WebFlux ServerResponse doesn't have generic with a type of body

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I've started using Spring WebFlux and recently I wondered why ServerResponse doesn't have generic with a body type. It's inconsistent with a synchronous ResponseEntity<> and kinda worsens general readability.

```
fun getAggregatedData(@RequestBody request: Request): Mono<ServerResponse>
```

Type of Response body in ServerResponse is unknown from this method's signature. 
Isn't is should be like below?

```
fun getAggregatedData(@RequestBody request: Request): Mono<ServerResponse<Response>>
```

I wonder what are the reasons behind ServerResponse to not have such generic type?

Answer (score 2):

`ServerResponse` is in the `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server` package, so it's meant to be used in [Spring WebFlux fn](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn).

As described in the reference documentation for Spring WebFlux annotations, [you can still use `ResponseEntity` as a return value for Controllers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-return-types).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for EntityResponse its a subtype of ServerResponse and has a generic type

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/EntityResponse.html